# How to combine 2 XLSX files into one using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx

I am currently working with generating XLSX spreadsheets using NodeJS. I am using the module xlsx-populate to create single-sheet XLSX files on an Express server.

I was wondering if anyone knew a way to combine multiple XLSX files into one file with multiple sheets using Node.

Thanks!

Example:

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx-populate');

xlsx.fromFileAsync('template1.xlsx')
  .then((workbook) => {
    // populate the workbook with stuff

    return workbook.toFileAsync('spreadsheet1.xlsx');
  })
  .then(() => xlsx.fromFileAsync('template2.xlsx'))
  .then((workbook) => {
    // populate the other workbook with stuff

    return workbook.toFileAsync('spreadsheet2.xlsx');
  });
```

This Promise chain saves two separate XLSX files (spreadsheet1.xlsx, spreadsheet2.xlsx), each being built from a corresponding template file. xlsx-populate does not let you create multiple sheets from different XLSX files on the same workbook, so I am wondering if it is possible to combine the two workbooks into one with multiple sheets?

**EDIT**

I ended up switching modules to excel4node which I found to be a more flexible, albeit more complex, module. My problem was that I had two template files, each containing an image, I wanted to merge into one file using xlsx-populate.

Since I failed to failed to find a successful way to merge the two templates to one file using xlsx-populate, I used excel4node to rebuild the template files from scratch, inserting the images (which xlsx-populate does not support).

Comment: Please include any relevant code and links to references you have used in your attempts.

Comment: have you tried just creating two node read streams and piping them to a single write stream?

Comment: @cheesenthusiast see the edit, hopefully more clear

Answer (score 4):

This snippet can merge two excel files into a new one.

```
 const XlsxPopulate = require('xlsx-populate');

 Promise.all([
    XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync('./src/data/template.xlsx'),
    XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync('./src/data/template2.xlsx')
 ])
  .then(workbooks => {
    const workbook = workbooks[0];
    const workbook2 = workbooks[1];
    const sheets2 = workbook2.sheets();

    sheets2.forEach(sheet => {
      const newSheet = workbook.addSheet(sheet.name());
      const usedRange = sheet.usedRange();
      const oldValues = usedRange.value();

      newSheet.range(usedRange.address()).value(oldValues);
    });

    return workbook.toFileAsync('./src/data/xlsx-populate/spreadsheet2.xlsx');
 });
```

**Known Issue:**

It will lose the second one's style, that's because the copy style feature was under development, please refer [here](https://github.com/dtjohnson/xlsx-populate/blob/master/backlog.md).

Answer (score 0):

**Adding a new worksheet to a workbook**

This example uses XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet to make a worksheet and appends the new worksheet to the workbook:

```
var new_ws_name = "SheetJS";

/* make worksheet */
var ws_data = [
    [ "S", "h", "e", "e", "t", "J", "S" ],
    [  1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ,  5 ]
];
var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);

/* Add the sheet name to the list */
wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);

/* Load the worksheet object */
wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;
```

from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#streaming-read